# Swift array reference and copy

Tags: arrays, swift, reference, assign

I'm quite new to Swift, Obj-c was my preferred language until now, but I decided to switch over. I read a book on Swift and I have a question about array assigning operation.

I read that arrays are generally assigned by reference until you perform some operation that alter the element count. But the problem is:

C++ old code

```
    int a[10];
    int b[10];

    // init a and b
    int* p; 

    if(...) 
       p = a;
    else 
       p = b;

    // do something with p
```

At this point `a` or `b` (depending on the `if`) are modified.

The above example works with Swift because no operation is done that alter the length of the arrays, but the question is: is there a way to do something above in Swift, i.e. using a reference even if you alter the length?

Many of you in this forum suggest re-assign:

```
    var a: [Int] = ...
    var b: [Int] = ...

    if ... {
       c = a
    }
    else {
       c = b
    }
    // do something with c, maybe extend c
```

then

```
    if ... {
       a = c
    }
    else {
       b = c
    }
```

But... i find this double check (the tow `if`s) annoying and ugly... I do not want believe Swift does not have some pointer-like operators :-)

Comment: Use `guard` instead?

Comment: Well, honestly I did not see that question.. OK, the accepted answer suggests to use a nested func... well I still think is not quite fast as the C++ code, but if this is the standard I will use it. So... Should I delete this question??

Comment: Nope. Dont. That's how you learn. Happy coding. :)

Comment: @Dershowitz123 if you please... would you give me an hint about your guard solution?